# Replacing list of data to DataFrame in efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing something like this to replace some `number-strings` to normal `number-strings` (I need a string because of front 0 in my `dataframe`)

```py
char_to_repalce = [('１', "1"), ('２', "2"), ('３', "3"), ('４', "4"), ('５', "5"),
                                ('６', "6"), ('７', "7"), ('８', "8"), ('９', "9"), ('０', "0"), ('O', "0")]
            for col in ['phone_number', 'phone_number2']:
                for char in char_to_repalce:
                    try:
                        df_data[col]=df_data[col].replace(char[0], char[1])
                    except:
                        pass
```

Which is not very effective way I think... There are also a normal numbers as well, but everything is a `string` as I need strings

Comment: Use `map` and a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have `replace` function which can accept `dict`

```
df[['phone_number', 'phone_number2']].replace(dict(char_to_repalce), inplace = True , regex=True)
```

My thought

```
df[['phone_number', 'phone_number2']].replace({' ':''}, inplace = True , regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This one works, but only in cell that contains only the number to replace. For example only `"５"` or so.  But my data looks like `"090５５３"`. It wont replace data like this.

Comment: @MarcelKopera also I think we can remove the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Given your `char_to_replace` variable, I would do the following using `map`:

```
replacers = {x[0]:x[1] for x in char_to_replace}
df = pd.DataFrame({'N1':['１','２','２','３','８'],
                   'N2':['９','５','７','０','O']}) 
df['N1'] = df['N1'].map(replacers)
df['N2'] = df['N2'].map(replacers)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  N1 N2
0  1  9
1  2  5
2  2  7
3  3  0
4  8  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But in my case everything becomes NaN ... isnt it because data looks like this? `"090５５３"`